# Inequality of the form $(R_{n+1})^{f(n)}<\prod_{k=1}^n R_k$, where $R_k$ is the $k$-th Ramanujan prime and $f(n)$ a suitable arithmetic function

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, products, prime-gaps

I'm curious to know if it is in the literature a similar/analogous statement about Ramanujan primes (this Wikipedia [*Ramanujan prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime) or [1]), than the known as Bonse's inequality for prime numbers (see from Wikipedia [*Bonse's inequality.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality)) Any case, if isn't in the literature I propose to get a remarkable improvement of my humble proposal (next claim).

For integers $k\geq 1$ let $R_k$ the $k$-th Ramanujan prime (sequence *A104272* from the OEIS).

**Claim.** *For each integer* $n\geq 4$ *the inequality* $$R_{n+1}^2<\prod_{k=1}^n R_k\tag{1}$$
*holds.*

*Sketch of proof.* We use **Theorem 2** (that is the first theorem of section 3) from [1]. Then it is sufficies to prove $(4(n+1)^2)^2<4^n n!$ for enough large $n$, and maybe add few computational examples as companion of this theoretical reasoning. $\square$

> **Question.** I would like to know if it is possible/feasible to get a remarkable improvement of previous inequality $(1)$ for a positive arithmetic function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, satisfying (that is increasing) $f(n+1)\geq f(n)$ and also $f(n)\geq 2$ let's say for all $n\geq n_0\geq 1$ (here, thus $n_0$ is a choice of a suitable constant in your inequality) with the purpose that
>   $$(R_{n+1})^{f(n)}<\prod_{k=1}^n R_k,\tag{2}$$
>   holds for all $n\geq n_0$. **Many thanks.**

Then explain your reasoning, or hints to get a remarkable improvement of $(1)$ of the form $(2)$ satisfying $\forall n\geq n_0$ for a suitable choice of $n_0$ and your arithmetic function $f(n)$.

I'm trying to get an answer, $n_0>1$, although I am not clear how to get a statement $(2)$ with a good mathematical content from the proposal

$$R_{n+1}^{W(n)}<\prod_{k=1}^n R_k,$$
where $W(x)$ is the principal/main branch of the Lambert $W$ function. I think that should be a nice proposal for some function $f(x)$ of slow increasing, with the goal to get an improvement of the proposal in previous **Claim** as was it  asked in my question.

### References:

[1] Jonathan Sondow, *Ramanujan Primes and Bertrand's Postulate*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 116, No. 7 (2009), pp. 630-635.

Comment: As a side remark if you want to know this information, in the literature there are different generalizations of Bonse's inequality for primes. See (I can do it, from my JSTOR account) Laurenţiu Panaitopol, *An inequality involving prime numbers*, Publikacije Elektrotehničkog fakulteta. Serija Matematika, No. 11 (2000), pp. 33-35, or the work by Posá.